# Best practice for accessing Page / controls on Page from other classes?

Tags: c#, refactoring

I'm refactoring some code and I've gotten into the practice of doing this:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Logger.Info("Page Initialization.");
    //Provides highlighting/docking functionality at the start, but overshadows controls in more complex scenarios.
    RadDockZone1.Visible = (RadControlStates.SplitterStates.Count == 0);

    ControlRegeneration.RegenerateReportMenu(lstBxHistorical, lstBxCustom);
    ControlRegeneration.RegeneratePaneChildren(RadPane2);
    ControlRegeneration.RegenerateDockZones(Page);
    ControlRegeneration.RegenerateDocks(RadDockLayout1, RadDock_Command, UpdatePanel1);
}
```

I'm wondering if it is good practice to pass Page and Page controls to other functions like this.

I was considering creating a singleton that will hold references to the relevant page controls, and then accessing the controls through that instance instead.

Something like...

```
public class DashboardPageControlsRepository
{
    private static readonly DashboardPageControlsRepository instance = new      DashboardPageControlsRepository();

    private DashboardPageControlsRepository() { }

    private Control myPanel;

    public static DashboardPageControlsRepository Instance
    {
        get { return instance; }
    }

    public void SetPageState(Page page)
    {
        myPanel = Utilities.FindControlRecursive(page, "UpdatePanel1")
    }

    public Control Panel
    {
        get { return myPanel; }
    }
}
```

Then, during page init before anything happens I would go and grab all my controls -- allowing me to access them through here rather than passing them down.

Any thoughts on how to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with creating singletons in this manner is that the static instance will exist for the lifetime of the AppDomain (until it is recycled). On top of that, multiple requests accessing the singleton will be attempting to mutate the singleton's state independently.

What services would this repository offer other than as a container for control references?

The other thing I would mention, is don't specialise your methods too much, you should consider the *least required type* approach to method design, e.g. you currently have:

```
public void SetPageSize(Page page)
```

In which the method is only really interested in accessing the `Controls` collection of the `System.Web.UI.Control` type. You could redefine the method as:

```
public void SetPageSize(Control control)
```